# Access subnet behind NAT

Tags: networking, routing, subnet

We will change our network provider in our company to get a faster link (VDSL2) soon. Currently we're running a TP-Link TD-W8980B which is only capable of ADSL2, so we can't use it anymore, but it has a lot configured and we also miss some features in the new AVM FritzBox 7360 we get for free from our provider.

So we plan to use the FritzBox as the VDSL2 router and put the TP-Link Router in WAN mode behind it. This should work fine. Now the problem:

1. Because there're some server running behind the TP-Link we need to forward the ports. What would be the best procedure? Forward all ports from the FritzBox (Exposed Host) to the IP-Adress of the TP-Link? Or is there a better way?
2. The TP-Link has the network 192.168.0.0/16 and the FritzBox should get the 10.0.1.0/24. Is there a way to access the TP-Link (192.168...) subnet from the FritzBox network (10.0....), to access the devices in there, although the TP-Link is hosting a NAT? We don't wan't to configure our subnet from the FritzBox. What is the best way? Is it possible to use routes?

Comment: Have you tried using Bridge mode for the FritzBox network ports? This should provide network transparency for your TP-Link and expose it directly on the internet.

Comment: What features don't you want to leave on the tp-link router?